# See what database a site is connected to

Tags: 7, configuration

Is there a page in Drupal 7 (or a module) that will show me what the name of the database is that the site is pointing to?

I know this can be done via settings.php, but I am setting up a build procedure that I can have lower level developers (or even non-developers) handle and a UI would be better.  I recently had an issue with two sites pointing to the same database and it borked some things up.  I want to add checking this setting to our build procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://drupal.org/project/show_database_name

> Display the host and database name of the default database on the status report, toolbar (Drupal 7) and/or on the admin_menu bar if enabled (either Drupal 6 or 7) and/or in a block (to use with the admin module).

It is marked as dev but it looks like a simple use-case and I don't expect there should be any problems.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I am looking for.  Thx and green check box to you, Sir.

Comment: I am also going to check out https://drupal.org/project/dbinfo, which was referenced as a related project.